# How to find string on page then add style to a particular div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, magento

I need to find a string on page then add style to a particular div with jQuery.

I want to find this string "**lang="de**"

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
```

When the lang="de" is found on page, i want to style a div class.
I have four languages on my store and i merged all the `lang.css` files from my system because of another issues.

I need to do this with `php` or `jQuery`.

Comment: I was going to blindly answer with a jQuery selector, but do you really need to add a class? Why not just use `:lang(de)` in your CSS? As recommended by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang)

Comment: @RGraham Your answer is the best. Simple as that. But will this work with IE7-10? IE is such a bad browser and i need to solve this with IE too because of my client

Comment: IE7+ supports attribute selectors: `[lang=de] { /* Your CSS */ }` you can use this for backwards compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('html').prop('lang') == 'de') {
    // do your thing...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest **Jquery 6.1 +** version. Please use

`$("html").prop("lang")` or you can use

`$("html").attr("lang")`

for older version of Jquery.